# Maven(Surefire) Exclude all Unit Test Cases but run selected

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

My company is in the middle of revamping the java code that has been written till now. Earlier there were some test cases written, but they were not maintained. As a result they are failing.
I have inherited this project, but currently have to make do with skipping all the tests.
I want to start by picking some unit test cases within a module fix them and add it to the suite of test cases that are being run. Over a period of time, I want to cover all the tests in my project.

I have tried the following plugin configuration in my POM file, but it is not working. Is there something I am missing ?

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/ParticularSubModuleTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Other option for me is to just to append all the current test classes with some suffix like UT and fix my test and rename fixed file as *Test.java and let the default configuration do its job

Comment: I strongly recommend to simply delete all those tests cause they have no value anymore if they do not work or even worse if they are failing they are blocking. Furthermore  the default naming convention is `*Test.java` for unit tests and `*IT.java` for integration tests (handled by maven-failsafe-plugin) If you want to run a single test just use command line `mvn -Dtest=XYZTest test` (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html). Do not start to use test suites..just let them being executed by naming convention. A test suite is a mess...